# Sitecore 10.1 sitecore_master_index taking 19 hours to rebuild

Tags: solr, indexing

We have migrated from **Sitecore 8.2 (solr 6.6.2)** to **Sitecore 10.1 (solr 8.4)**.

The rebuild **sitecore_master_index** in **Sitecore 10.1** is taking **19 hours** while it used to take less than **2 hours** in **Sitecore 8.2**.

The number of document count of **sitecore_master_index** in **Sitecore 8.2** was **43919** which is jumped to **569279** **documents** in **Sitecore 10.1**.

I compared the **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config** in Sitecore 8.2 and Sitecore 10.1

**Sitecore 8.2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="core">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
            </strategies>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
            <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
            <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Sitecore 10.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement" search:require="solr">
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="core">sitecore_master_index</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
              <enableReadAccessIndexing>true</enableReadAccessIndexing>
            </configuration>
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/manual" role:require="ContentManagement and !Indexing" />
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncMaster" role:require="Standalone or (ContentManagement and Indexing)" />
            </strategies>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
            <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
            <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Has anyone faced the issue? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many documents are in the sitecore_web_index?

Comment: If you have any computed fields configured against the master index, you might try disabling them and rebuilding.

Comment: @ChetCheeto I dont have any computed fields

Comment: @MichaelWest I have not published anything in web yet. Everything is in the master database. All the site grouping is using master database. That could be the reason of large number of documents?

Comment: I was curious so you would have a point of reference. Web contains a single version of items so you could see how the web index looks. Perhaps you have more items in Sitecore than you realize? Compare show config.aspx to see what has changed.

Comment: Maybe try to disable media items indexing and see if that's the reason why it's so slow? E.g. see https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.DisableMediaIndexing/blob/master/src/Sitecore.Support.DisableMediaIndexing/9.0%2B/App_Config/Include/zzz/Sitecore.Support.DisableMediaIndexing.config

Comment: Check difference in solrconfig.xml between the two versions.